# How to remove the "span" space that surrounds sections in UITableViews?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm trying to add a background image (using a pattern) to a grouped TableView. The problem is that each TableViewCell (and also its header and footer) is surrounded by a space that takes the same background image as the one that I'm setting to the TableView, and the image is used from the top by each Cell. This is noticeable since the image has horizontal strips, and is very annoying when scrolling, because in between this spaces you can see in the back the actual background of the TableView (that is the same), creating a weird effect.

Here I'm attaching a screenshot, but is not that clear as when scrolling.

[image]

I've tried setting the Cell background to ClearColor, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to set a clear background view.  For example, putting the following in your custom cell's initializer ought to do the trick:

```
    [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    UIView *blankBackgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    [blankBackgroundView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [self setBackgroundView:blankBackgroundView];
    [self setSelectedBackgroundView:blankBackgroundView];
    [blankBackgroundView release];
```